# Iview UI Table Cell

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview

How can I access the cell data in a library iview table for Vuejs when I click on it? I need the cell table value and column title after that change the cell table css. For example, if I click in a cell and it turn red, in a other cell, it turn green

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <Table border :columns="columns7" :data="data6"></Table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                columns7: [
                    {
                        title: 'Age',
                        key: 'age'
                    },
                    /* blah blah blah...*/
                    {
                        title: 'Action',
                        key: 'action',
                        width: 150,
                        align: 'center',
                        render: (h, params) => {
                            return h('div', [
                                h('Button', {
                                    props: {
                                        type: 'primary',
                                        size: 'small'
                                    },
                                    style: {
                                        marginRight: '5px'
                                    },
                                    on: {//here you can pass event handlers
                                        click: () => {
                                            this.show(params.index)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 'View'),
                                h('Button', {
                                    props: {
                                        type: 'error',
                                        size: 'small'
                                    },
                                    on: {
                                        click: () => {
                                            this.remove(params.index)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 'Delete')
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                ],
                data6: [
                    {
                        name: 'John Brown',
                        age: 18,
                        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Jim Green',
                        age: 24,
                        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Joe Black',
                        age: 30,
                        address: 'Sydney No. 1 Lake Park'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Jon Snow',
                        age: 26,
                        address: 'Ottawa No. 2 Lake Park'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            show (index) {
                this.$Modal.info({
                    title: 'User Info',
                    content: `Name：${this.data6[index].name}<br>Age:${this.data6[index].age}<br>Address：${this.data6[index].address}`
                })
            },
            remove (index) {
                this.data6.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can provide render function in columns definition. (And in render function you can "bind" event receivers).
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/),[iview doc](https://www.iviewui.com/components/table-en#Custom%20Column%20Template),[Vue - render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)